# Concatenating selected columns from two data frames in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate some of the columns in my data frame in python pandas. Say, I have the following data frames:

> df1['Head','Body','feat1','feat2']
>
> df2['Head','Body','feat3','feat4']

I want to merge the dataframes into:

> merged_df['Head','Body','feat1','feat2','feat3',feat4']

Intuitively, I did this:

```
merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2['feat3','feat4'],axis=1)
```

It did not work. I did my research and did this:

```
merged_df = 
df1[['Head','Body','feat1','feat2']].merge(df2[['Head','feat3','feat4']], 
on='Head', how='left')
```

It worked but caused some discrepancies on my data. Turns out some of my 'Head' data are not unique. So now I am just looking for the most straight forward way to concatenate the selected columns from DF2 into my DF1. Note that both data frames follow the same order, so the row 1 in DF1 is directly related to row 1 in DF2, so is the row 8120th and so on..

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a small dataset and expected output?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,on=['Head','Body'],how='left')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

taking an example, lets suppose we have two DataFrame's as `df1` and `df2`, so, if the values are of the columns are same or unique across then you simple do merge which will align the columns as you desired.

```
$ df1
   Head  Body  feat1  feat2
0     1     1      1      1
1     2     2      2      2
2     3     3      3      3


$ df2
   Head  Body  feat3  feat4
0     1     1      1      1
1     2     2      2      2
2     3     3      3      3
```

**Step 1 solution:**

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Head',  'Body'])
   Head  Body  feat1  feat2  feat3  feat4
0     1     1      1      1      1      1
1     2     2      2      2      2      2
2     3     3      3      3      3      3
```

**Secondly**, if you have the columns values are different as follows then you can use pd.concat or pd.merge:

```
$ df1
   Head  Body  feat1  feat2
0     1     1      1      1
1     2     2      2      2
2     3     3      3      3

$ df2
   Head  Body  feat3  feat4
0     4     1      1      1
1     5     2      2      2
2     6     3      3      3
```

**Step 2 solution:**

If you want to use union of keys from both frames, then you can do it both with `concat` and `merge` as follows:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1,df2], join="outer", sort=False)
   Head  Body  feat1  feat2  feat3  feat4
0     1     1    1.0    1.0    NaN    NaN
1     2     2    2.0    2.0    NaN    NaN
2     3     3    3.0    3.0    NaN    NaN
0     4     1    NaN    NaN    1.0    1.0
1     5     2    NaN    NaN    2.0    2.0
2     6     3    NaN    NaN    3.0    3.0


>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Head',  'Body'], how='outer')
   Head  Body  feat1  feat2  feat3  feat4
0     1     1    1.0    1.0    NaN    NaN
1     2     2    2.0    2.0    NaN    NaN
2     3     3    3.0    3.0    NaN    NaN
3     4     1    NaN    NaN    1.0    1.0
4     5     2    NaN    NaN    2.0    2.0
5     6     3    NaN    NaN    3.0    3.0
```

Or you can opt to have :

a) if you want to use keys from left frame

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Head',  'Body'], how='left')
```

b) if you want to use keys from right frame

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Head',  'Body'], how='right')
```

Default it takes 'inner'.

> inner: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL
>   inner join; preserve the order of the left keys

You Can see [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for detail options..

After looking at your workaround, you want to use the keys from `left frame`

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Head',  'Body'], how='left')
   Head  Body  feat1  feat2  feat3  feat4
0     1     1      1      1    NaN    NaN
1     2     2      2      2    NaN    NaN
2     3     3      3      3    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you.. this post have been very helpful.

Comment: You Welcome,  by the way what made you to switch the answer? what is your desired output ,  this was what explained in your post

Comment: Both are correct though.. Yours was well explained. I think the basic pandas data frame tutorials out there misses this type of merging. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need value assign , and it will ignore index

```
df1['feat3']=df2['feat3'].values
df1['feat4']=df2['feat4'].values
```